# Get column attributes from fluent API EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have some required columns for class 'c' and setting its with fluent API:

```
Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired()
```

How I can find out that 'c.Name' is required in my code without using data annotation ?

Comment: you want to check it by write test?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply mean how you can check the property without fluent you could try

```
@Model.Name.IsRequired()
```